# Issue with File Path Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with asp.net application my user has to create a csv file and then save it on local or network drive . My approach to solve this problem is creating a folder inside my project where file is created then i use HTTP handler to download that file and save it to other location . But i am getting problem when i re-direct to HTTP handler i got an 404 error here is my code .

```
 private String serverPath = "\\PerformanceAttributionWeb\\PerfAttribution\\ExportData\\";



var   fileName  = serverPath + txtFileName.Text;
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Create(fileName).Close();
        }
Response.Redirect(string.Format("ExportData/CsvFileHandler.ashx?FileToDownload={0}", fileName));
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var fileName = request.QueryString["FileToDownload"];
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                           "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(fileName);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
```

Comment: No need for a handler at all. You can send the file directly. No need for a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual directory in IIS pointing to the export folder. Then used a http url to access the file. Make sure the folder is  accessible by everyone.